# Raster pixel aspect ratio gets distorted when exporting from Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, mosaic

*Problem:*
I have a mosaic of a Landsat 7 collection in Google Earth Engine that looks alright on display (*pre-export-version*) in the map window of the web app. However, when I export it, some pixels get narrower and some wider. Basically there are north-south columns with pixels that are 22 m wide instead of 30m. (see attached screenshot)

*Question:*
Why does this happen? Is there any way to avoid it?

[image]

*Investigation:*
I investigated the output in QGIS, but if I upload the exported image back into Earth Engine this difference remains, so it does not appear to be a platform dependent problem.

If I use the inspector function, the pre-export and the export-imported file have different pixel values where the overlap is distorted, so it is not just a display error.

If I do the same thing with an image from the same collection (just the raw image, no mosaic), the exported file looks identical to the original.

I have tried to export using different coordinate references such as WGS84 and different UTM-zones. None of this affects the result.

*Thoughts:*
First I thought that difference between the mosaic and the raw image could imply that the irregularities are a result from the mosaic operation trying to fit pixels with slightly different spatial location into the same raster. But if so, I do not really get why that is not showing in the pre-export render of the raster.

*Reproducible example:* (or see link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ecceca28e81cc3d0c304281f08b4619)

```
// Define study site geometry:
var box = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(14.91081234991633, 68.28371077192794, 14.965572329164377, 68.30250393637535);
Map.centerObject(box);

// Filter image collection by time and area.
var landsat_7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR") // 
  .filterBounds(box)
  .filterDate('2000-07-01','2000-08-31');

// Make median mosaic from collection:  
var landsat_7_mosaic = landsat_7.median()
  .select('B.+'); // Keep only bands containing B

var visuals = {bands: ["B1","B2","B3"],
    gamma: 1,
    max: 2737.5867438745377,
    min: 2040.6889200176545,
    opacity: 1};

// Add the image to the map window
Map.addLayer(landsat_7_mosaic, visuals, 'Landsat 7 mosaic');
             
Export.image.toDrive({image: landsat_7_mosaic,
                       description:'imageToDriveExample',
                       scale:30,
                       region: box,
                       maxPixels:1e13});

// Import the export and add to map to compare with the pre-export
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default GEE exports images in EPSG:4326 which leads to the rectangle looking pixels at this latitude. It is always best to reproject the image at export to the native projection - in your case EPSG:32633. This should solve the issue: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d93bebc73ffda84bb0a390982c725b34

```
// Define study site geometry:
var box = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(14.91081234991633, 68.28371077192794, 14.965572329164377, 68.30250393637535);
Map.centerObject(box);
Map.addLayer(box)

// Filter image collection
var landsat_7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR") // Use var to make an object containing the landsat 5 catalogue.
  .filterBounds(box)
  .filterDate('2000-07-01','2000-08-31');

// Make median mosaic from collection:  
var landsat_7_mosaic = landsat_7.median()
  .select('B.+'); // Keep only bands containing B
print(landsat_7)
var visuals = {bands: ["B1","B2","B3"],
    gamma: 1,
    max: 2737.5867438745377,
    min: 2040.6889200176545,
    opacity: 1};

// Add the image to the map window
Map.addLayer(landsat_7_mosaic, visuals, 'Landsat 7 mosaic');

             
Export.image.toDrive({image: landsat_7_mosaic.select(["B1","B2","B3"]),
                       description:'mosaic_epsg4326',
                       scale:30,
                       region: box,
                       maxPixels:1e13});
                       
var proj = landsat_7.first().select(0).projection();
print(proj)
Export.image.toDrive({image: landsat_7_mosaic.select(["B1","B2","B3"]).reproject(proj),
                       description:'mosaic_reproj_epsg32633',
                       scale:30,
                       region: box,
                       maxPixels:1e13});
```